# Update android app without changing version number

Tags: android, xamarin, google-play, google-play-console

I wonder if it is possible to update an android app without increasing the version number.

I am asking this question because every time I implement something small in my app, I need to update it in the Play Store, then I have to provide a new higher version number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When publishing an update to an application you have 2 elements

**versionCode** -  You cannot upload an APK to the Play Store with a versionCode you have already used for a previous version.

**versionName** -  The value is a string so that you can describe the app version as a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or relative version identifier. The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users.

You can update an existing app without changing its version name, however you always have to change the versionCode.

You can check the [official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)